# How to crop using a virtual canvas (trim result)?

Tags: canvas, imagemagick, crop

I `trim`med an image using ImageMagick:

```
step2.png[0] PNG 1200x1200=>264x468 1200x1200+381+273 8-bit sRGB 0.031u 0:00.014
step3.png[0] PNG 264x468 1200x1200+381+273 8-bit sRGB 31.8KB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

Now, I'd like to use the area found by trim (a 264x468 px area starting at 381,273) to crop another image (the precursor to step2.png). How can I do this programmatically, i.e. without copy-pasting 381,273,etc from the `-identify` output?

My idea was to make an alpha mask of step3.png and compose it with the original image, but I couldn't figure out how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

On reflection, I think you maybe mean this, where `other.png` gets trimmed to match `trimmed_orig.png`:

```
composite -compose src other.png trimmed_orig.png trimmed_other.png
```

where the images are like this:

```
identify other.png trimmed_orig.png trimmed_other.png

other.png PNG 560x360 560x360+0+0 8-bit sRGB 2c 312B 0.000u 0:00.000
trimmed_orig.png PNG 400x200 560x360+80+80 8-bit sRGB 2c 340B 0.000u 0:00.000
trimmed_other.png PNG 400x200 560x360+80+80 8-bit sRGB 2c 340B 0.000u 0:00.000
```

**Original Answer**

Not sure if you mean the following or explicitly not the following, but let's try and see.

Suppose you start with this image:

[image]

and you want to trim off the red, and find where the inner, blue area is. You could do this:

```
convert image.png -trim trimmed.png
```

and you would get a blue 400x200 image offset 80,80 from the top-left corner. Rather than do that though, you could ask ImageMagick to tell you what it would trim without doing so, using `-format %@` like this:

```
convert image.png -format "%@" info:
400x200+80+80
```

So, you would then capture that like this:

```
trim=$(convert image.png -format"%@" info:)
```

Now if you have another image like this:

[image]

you can trim it using the same area as you meant to trim from the original image like this:

```
convert other.png -crop $trim cropped.png
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using ImageMagick 7+, you can do this pretty easily with fx expressions by stashing the size of one image and using it as the trim size for another:

```
magick \( \
    step3.png -set option:trimzone "%[fx:w]x%[fx:h]+%[fx:page.x]+%[fx:page.y]" +delete \
    \) other_image.png -crop %[trimzone] output.png
```

Honestly you can probably eliminate most or all of your intermediate "step x" files as well, but without more detail on your process it's hard to say how.